# can't upload file to wordpress

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, ubuntu, cpanel

I move my wordpress website to my vps with Cpanel, after move every thing is working well, but my media option can't upload file to my library, I try to set permission for uploads folder and subfolders to 755,775 even 777 but media uploader get me this error :

> The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads/2016/10.

I try to solve my problem with set group and owner with terminal linux to my user,

```
> sudo chown -R username:group directory
> sudo chgrp -R username:group directory
```

but my problem not solved.

**Edited :**

I try to install "SuPHP" and my problem solved...

for more information see :
https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/EA/Apache+Module%3A+SuPHP

Comment: http://2surge.com/how-to-fix-the-uploaded-file-could-not-be-moved-to-wp-content-error-message/

Comment: thanks, it solved my problem, please write this post as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks smoqadam

I try to this :

```
 chown -R nobody /home/<username>/public_html/wp-content/uploads/
```

and everything is OK...

Comment: Glad that you solved it . But you should not have posted this as an answer yourself. Instead you should have invited @smoqadam to post his comment as answer. Happy coding mate.

Comment: The answer is matter, not the person who answer. just select your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would strongly recommend not setting your permissions to 777. This is a serious security concern. The user wp-user does not exist by default on Ubuntu and is likely left over from the host you exported your site from. All your web files should be owned by www-data. Assuming your web root remains /var/www/html (the default on the WP one-click image) you can fix the ownership with:

```
chown -Rf www-data:www-data /var/www/html
```

If that doesn't work you can update the perminssions of the upload folder using the following command

```
chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data <path_to_your_web_root>
```

(If that still doesn't work, make sure the uploads folder etc. are not at 777 permission - you can use this for that purpose:
`sudo chmod -R 755 <path_to_your_web_root>` )
)